# wpf RibbonMenuButton item

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have to use RibbonMenuButton, but I need when it is clicked, the result to be as the following:

[image]

In other words, I need a grid to be opened with some buttons in it. I don't know how to do that.
This is my code so far,

```
<RibbonMenuButton Label="{Binding AppsLabel, Source={StaticResource ribbonStrings}}"
      LargeImageSource="{x:Static Member=util:ImageUtil.CGSnapToGridIcon}" x:Name="zzz" >     
    <Grid Height="auto" Width="auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <RibbonButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" LargeImageSource="{}" Label="Reporting"></RibbonButton>
        <RibbonButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" LargeImageSource="{}" Label="Discovery"></RibbonButton>
        <RibbonButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" LargeImageSource="{}" Label="Web"></RibbonButton>
        <RibbonSeparator Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"></RibbonSeparator>
        <RibbonButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" LargeImageSource="{}" Label="Content"></RibbonButton>
        <RibbonButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" LargeImageSource="{}" Label="Delete"></RibbonButton>
    </Grid>
</RibbonMenuButton>
```

but the whole grid is highlighted when the content pops up and a grey line (for the menu items) is shown on the left side. I need to get rid of them.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found how to do that, here is the solution:

I've put the grid inside `<ItemsControl>` and after that I've applied style to it as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RibbonMenuItem}">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
```

This simply makes the grid (or whatever is inside the `<RibbonMenuButton>`) unselectable and as a result the content appears as a normal control but not as a RibbonMenuItem.

Comment: I want to do similar, but your solution did not work for me. The dropdown menu/window/panel still shows as a menu item; selectable.